# Use PowerShell to Overwrite entire contents of multiple *.txt files at the same time

Tags: powershell, text, overwrite

I'm trying to write a quick script to "reset" some files I'm using to gather results from another script.  I don't always want them reset, and I don't want the other people using the original scripts to be able to reset them, so I just need a simple script to do this, but can't seem to find anything...  The closest thing I've found is this, but it's not quite what I'm looking for:

```
Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot\*.txt" -Recurse | ForEach {
(Set-Content $_ | ForEach { $_ -replace '', 'Currently no results' }) |
Set-Content $_
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [Clear-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/clear-content?view=powershell-6), which can be used to 'blank' multiple files with one command.

Comment: I tried that as well, but wasn't sure how to add to each file once I was done with it.

Comment: What do you mean by *"add to each file"*?

Comment: I want each file to read "Currently no results."  I know it seems redundant, but my other scripts are dependent on contents of these files, so I need to have something in them.

Comment: Sounds like you want [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6#examples) instead then.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot\*.txt" -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_ | Set-Content -Value 'Currently no results' -Whatif }`

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe `Get-ChildItem` output directly to `Set-Content` with a static `-Value` argument that fills all input files with the same string:

```
Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot\*.txt -Recurse |
  Set-Content -Value 'Currently no results' -WhatIf
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` *previews* the operation; remove it to actually overwrite the files' contents.</sup>